# Commandering GTKWindow

Tags: user-interface, gtk, window, gtk#

Is there a way to easily to have child GTK applications start in a GtkWindow of
the parent's application choice?  Or would this require changing the Gtk libraries?

Comment: I dont understand. What do you mean by child application? Can you be more descriptive?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood question correctly, then you should use GtkPlug/GtkSocket for embedding one application into another.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `GtkSocket::steal()` function that sounds about right, but it has been deprecated. As dmitry-vk mentioned, look into the rest of the Socket/Plug pair API to figure out how it's done nowadays.